# Why is PHP SoapClient / Webservice not giving a response?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I have a script that consumes a webservice through SOAP. I'm wondering why I don't receive a response from the server/endpoint URL. The other side said that they're receiving my requests so it means the script works. The only problem is that it doesn't give me a response. I also tried to get the last request, last request header and last response but nothing happens.

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Here's my code:

```
$wsdl = "http://imupost.co.za/momentum/CRMLeadService.wsdl";
$momurl = "https://integrationdev.momentum.co.za/sales/CRMService/CRMLeadService_v1_0";
echo("Post to URL: {$momurl}\n");
$username = "817221";
$password = "1234";

echo("<pre>");
$client = new SoapClient ($wsdl, array('location' => $momurl, 'style' => SOAP_DOCUMENT, 'trace' => 1,  'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1, 'exceptions' => true, 'compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP, 'ssl_method' => SOAP_SSL_METHOD_TLS));

$header='
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-45">
            <wsse:Username>'.$username.'</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">'.$password.'</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
    ';

$headerSoapVar = new SoapVar($header,XSD_ANYXML); 
$soapheader = new SoapHeader('wsse', "Security" , $headerSoapVar , true);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($soapheader);

$params['createLead'] = array(
    'LeadSourceId' => '07d3d6fe-7682-e311-a16d-005056b81ea8',
    'AffiliateLeadReference' => '852800020',
    'Title' => array('Code' => '852800018'),
    'Initials' => 'MH',
    'PreferredName' => 'Jane',
    'FirstName' => 'Hudson',
    'LastName' => 'Craig',
    'PreferredCorrespondenceLanguage' => array('Code' => '852800001'),
    'PreferredCommunicationMethod' => array('Code' =>'852800000'),
    'HomePhoneNumber' => '0725222427',
    'BusinessPhoneNumber' => '0725584155',
    'MobilePhoneNumber' => '0723694259',
    'EmailAddress' => 'jhudson@gmail.com',
    'Notes' => 'IMU',
    'ProductCategories' => array('Code' => '9c7d3878-5295-e211-9330-005056b81ea8', 'Description' => 'Health - Personal')
); 

    $result = $client->__soapCall("createLead", array($params));
    echo "REQUEST:\n" . htmlentities($client->__getLastRequest())  . "\n";
    echo "RESPONSE:\n" . $client->__getLastResponse()  . "\n";
    print_r($client->__getLastRequestHeaders());
```

Comment: Sorry that was not correct answer.I deleted that. Can you paste your request message which is being received by server? I saw your wsdl, there are lots of different namespaces in it. I don't know whether this code is forming your request as per required by server.

Comment: That's also a problem. As you could see on my code, I tried to print out the request but there's nothing displayed. Even the request headers cannot be displayed. But the other side told me that they've received the request. It's kinda weird.

Comment: @kingAm Ok, here's what the request should look like: http://hastebin.com/moxicisani.xml

Comment: I have checked your soap request by comparing it using soap ui soap request. Its perfect. Only problem is in receiving your response. what's is echo $result showing?

Comment: Yes, I've been testing it with SOAPUI too and it's working very well. echo $result is not showing anything.

Comment: have you put your `$result = $client->__soapCall("createLead", array($params));` in a `try{} catch(){}` to see if you are actually getting an error from the server instead of a response?

Comment: In the other code that I've written, I used try catch but I'm still not getting a response... Do you have other suggestions on how to make this work? It's been days already and I'm not having any progress...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a try catch.

```
try {
  $client->__soapCall("createLead", array($params));
  echo $client->__getLastResponse();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "<pre>Exception: ".print_r($e, true)."</pre>\n";
}
```